# How to use this regex with grep in shell script?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, perl, grep

I need to extract the public key in the shell script, Not sure how to use this. I am new to shell script.
https://regex101.com/r/SXDEaU/1

Content of the file:

```
public_key=#STARTKEY#<public key base64 encoded>#ENDKEY#
```

Regex: `/public_key=#STARTKEY#(.*)#ENDKEY#/s`

Since the key is base64 encoded, it is a multiline string.

**Desired output:**
<public key base64 encoded>

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `grep -Pzo '(?<=public_key=#STARTKEY#)[\s\S]*(?=#ENDKEY#)' file` ?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` using its `RS` variable and setting it to paragraph mode please try following code.

```
awk -v RS= 'match($0,/public_key=#STARTKEY#.*#ENDKEY#/){print substr($0,RSTART+21,RLENGTH-29)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: That doesn't support blanks lines. But while allowed, one is extremely unlikely to encounter any. So this is probably not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
perl -M5.010 -0777ne'say for /public_key=#STARTKEY#(.*?)#ENDKEY#/s' file
```

The key is `-0777` which causes the entire file to be read in as one line.

Comment: I would use `([^#]*)` instead of `(.*)`, then strip all non base64 characters (like newlines) from the match

Comment: @Fravadona, I didn't look at the pattern; I just showed how to use it as requested. `[^#]*` isn't correct, That should be `(?:(?!#ENDKEY#).)*`. But `.*?` would do just as well here, and it would be better than `.*`. Adjusted answer. /// Stripping non-base64 characters wasn't requested, isn't always desirable, and can't be done without knowing which flavour of base64 is being used.

Comment: Oh yes, of course perl has non greedy `*`